# Automatic Reboot after Kernel Panic

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kernel, kernel-panic

I am currently running Ubuntu 9.04, Jaunty, and have had some issues that caused a few kernel panics to crop up. These panics cause the system to dump a bunch of information to the terminal and hang.

More often than not, these happen while I am away from the system. This means that the system sits idle until I come to the terminal, see that it has had a kernel panic, and restart the system.

Is there a way to automate the restart with Linux? I know that with a Windows BSOD, there is an option to automatically reboot after the core dump has occurred. Is there a similar option for Linux?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Add the following to `/etc/sysctl.conf`:

```
kernel.panic = 20
```

It will reboot after a panic after 20 seconds.

To activate the setting immediately, run:

```
sysctl -p
```

Comment: you mean `sysctl -p`